# Can you keep on adding things in a list till a certain point?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

Let's say I wanted to add all items in a list. One of the issues is, this list can go on forever. Here's an example:

```
a = 0
lst = [int(0)]
ItemsInList = int(input("How many items do you want in this list? "))
while a != ItemsInList:
    a + 1
    Item = int(input("What should item", a, "be? "))
    lst.append(Item)
```

Now I want to add all those together. I cannot do print(lst[0] + lst[1] + lst[2] + lst[3] etc etc.. because if I were to do that and the list were to have more items then 3 I wouldn't have added the whole list. If I were  to just do that again and again and again until it reached lst[500] I would get an error because that item probably wont exist most of the time. I'm thinking of making a while command inside the print() but I can't figure out if that is possible or not. Any ideas of simplifying that code or just helping me with the actual issue would be much appreciated. This is to make a mean average calculator by the way.

Comment: Did my answer help u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add all the items in a list, just use the `sum` method, like this:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
print(sum(lst))
```

Output:

```
6
```

But instead of appending all the inputs to a list, you can have a running total, like this:

```
total = 0
for a in range(ItemsInList):
    Item = int(input("What should item", a, "be? "))
    total += Item
```

This would work faster than the code that you're using currently.

Apart from that, there are many flaws in your code, like:

1. `a+1`. You did not assign the resulting value to `a`, so the loop would be infinite. It should instead be `a += 1` or `a = a+1`
2. Using a `while` loop when you know how many times you want to execute the loop.
3. `lst = [int(0)]`. This isn't wrong, but this isn't the right way either to initialize a list. You can do it like this: `lst = []`

Make sure that you don't repeat these mistakes! Hope that this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try these. You're very helpful. Have a nice day!